# Extension to return DBnull when a string is null

Tags: c#, string, extension-methods

I am trying to create a custom extension for a string in C#, please find below example, my requirement is that this extension should return `DBNull` when the string is not valid, else it should return the text. How to do this.
`My Factory.IsValidString` has all the checks to determine if a string is valid.

```
public static string DBString(this string Text)
{
    return (!Factory.ISValidString(Text)) ? DBNull: Text;
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `DBString`

Comment: So what is your problem? Do you get any errors or unexpected results?

Comment: `DBNull` and `string` are different types, and they have no common parent type except `object`, so your extension method should return `object` and not `string`

Comment: And now combine Evk's explanation with kara's code and you have the almost perfect answer.

Comment: kara's explanation has been updated for this

Comment: Thank you soo much all, it's working, i am using Sql Server

Comment: @PrasanthKumarVinakota you may rethink the return type. Chekc my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **Evk** said in comments to your post:

> `DBNull` and `string` are different types, and they have no common
>   parent type except object, so your extension method **should return
>   `object` and not `string`**

So you should refactor your extension method like below:

```
public static object DBString(this string Text)
{
    return (!Factory.ISValidString(Text)) ? (object)DBNull.Value: Text;
}
```

Bear in mind that you may need to cast the returned object to `string` or `DBNull` depending on what the code that uses it is doing.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using an `DBNull.Value` just use `SqlString.Null` and change the return type to `SqlString` and no cast is needed here because it exists an implicit conversion between `string` and `SqlString`:

```
public static SqlString DBString(this string Text)
{
    return (!Factory.ISValidString(Text)) ? SqlString.Null : Text;
}
```

This solution let the caller know that he is dealing with a `SqlString` type and not just an `object` type which may contains anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works, but in this case i will have to define extension methods for each SqlType that i use, whereas the other method with object return type returns DBNull which can be assigned to any SqlType.